# Opencv: get wrong specific frame by using cv2.videocapture.set(CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC/CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)

Tags: python, opencv

I came across a bug.I failed to get specific frame in .mov video using `cap.set(CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC/CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)` with opencv 3.4.2 in python 2.7.3 .Is there someone encountering the situation on .mov video.

The pipeline of my system is to detect key frames by some algorithm on video with cap.read() from first frame to end.And then i will save the key frame id which is counted by myself.Finally ,i use cap.set(CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC/CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) to fetch the specific frame in video by key frame id aformentationed.
Here is the code:

```py
def detectkeyframe():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    frame_id = 0
    key_frame_ids=[]
    while True:
        ret,frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        if it is a key frame:
            key_frame_ids.append(frame_id)
            cv2.imwrite(frame)  #saved for comparing
        frame_id +=1

def dumpkeyframe(key_frame_ids):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    for frame_id in key_frame_ids:
        cap.set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,frame_id)
        #cap.set(CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,timeofframe_id)  #it is also useless
        ret,frame = cap.read()    #frame obtained is always ahead of the real frame i want
        cv2.imwrite(frame)
```

the frame saved by two function is not the same,the frame from `dumpkeyframe()` is always ahead of the frame from `detectkeyframe()`
Is there someone telling me where is wrong?
I caught some similar problems others came across :[a open problem in opencv github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9053)

Comment: Hey @Bob, did you manage to get your problem fixed? It seems OpenCV added some fixes to issue you linked.